# Can redirecting a spammy site with less PageRank to a site with higher PageRank hurt?

Tags: seo, redirects, pagerank

How does it affect a site with higher PageRank if a lower PageRank start redirecting (301) to it?

The lower ranked site has a spammy link profile and would like to shut it down, but it also has a lot of visitors. I would like to start redirecting it to another site with much higher rank.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want the weight placed by a search engine to carry over to the new website because along with it, will be transferred all the negative weight from low quality / spammy content/links etc.

In order to just refer legitimate traffic to the new website, you'd need to implement a 301 redirect and exclude search engine crawlers such as `GoogleBot` so that they do not get redirected to the new website. (So you'd be redirecting humans and not bots). You'd have to be wary of potential [cloaking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloaking) risks though.

Alternatively, could you not just display a notification or new page at your old website advising all visitors of the new website and ask them to visit that one instead?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely, you are going to lose your high PageRank site too. Google can easily detect that the traffic is coming from a spammy site, therefore the new hummingbird algorithm will classify your blog too in the list of spams, especially when you do a 301 redirect.
**That doesn't mean that the high PageRank of your site will decrease**.

You could possible do one thing. In the Google Webmaster Tools, try to file a manual spam action reverting. Delete all the spam posts in your blog and then try a redirect.

Comment: The Hummingbird algorithm has nothing to do with detecting/combating spam.

Answer (score 0):

A 301 redirect should be the correct thing to do. Here's a reference: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/83105?hl=en.

Make sure that you do not do a single redirect for all the pages but for one page at a time.

Comment: That link doesn't answer his questions about spam on on one domain having a negative effect on the other domain.